# queryRunner.getRepository(SomeEntity).save(someEntity) does not work while someEntity.save() works

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm doing this:

```
            const slot = await LocationTimeSlotEntity.findOneOrFail(slotId);

            const fight = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(FightEntity)
                                                   .findOneOrFail({
                                                       where: {
                                                           id: fightId,
                                                           target: userId,
                                                           status: EFightStatus.PENDING,
                                                           slot: slotId,
                                                       }
                                                   });
            fight.status = EFightStatus.CONFIRMED;
            slot.fight = fight;
            await Promise.all(
                [
                    queryRunner.manager.getRepository(LocationTimeSlotEntity)
                                       .save(slot),
                    queryRunner.manager.getRepository(FightEntity)
                                       .save(fight),
                ]
            );
```

and the Promise.all part doesn't seem to work, but when I use this line instead:

```
await Promise.all([slot.save(), fight.save()]);
```

it works.

How come? According to the doc this is the same `save` function. What am I missing here?

I think the right way to do this is by using queryRunner , that's, within the initiated transaction. But it just won't work...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
queryRunner.manager.save(slot)
```

instesd of

```
queryRunner.manager.getRepository(LocationTimeSlotEntity).save(slot)
```

*the queryRunner will understand to use the correct repository :)*

for example:

```
import User from '../../User.entity.ts'

// record: User;

const record = await this.userRepository.findOne(1);
// now the type of record is 'User'
queryRunner.manager.save(record);
```